# How are the feature map visualizations generated?

Tags: machine-learning

In most CNN papers they try to visualize their feature maps for each layer, for example in :
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8739137?casa_token=mpQfdl2GJLYAAAAA:bci8BEKNgkjQWckwy9zlCAUAhDQ6ny2eco95lYVosvo31Q5M_D6-5tZPC7ky2yqaPefm30tkxdQ
Their visualization looks like this:
[image: Text]
The two convolutional layers both have 32 filters each.

My question is where does the color come from since each feature map should only have one channel?